# Get messaging thread from Twilio

Tags: twilio

I am creating a web server that is using Twilio to send / receive messages.

The problem that I am facing is that Twilio uses sender and receiver phone number as a key for a cookie. But in my case, user can have multiple conversations with a server.

As I can think of the solution, the only was would be that I pass all the time cookie that will say which *conversatation_id* that conversation belongs to.

But since the cookie expiration time is 4h, what would happen if the first sms that I send has cookie *conversation_id* attached, and the person who received sms replies after 4h. Would I still get *conversation_id* cookie attached to the message?

Can someone suggest better way of solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist.

There is no way to conduct multiple different conversations between two numbers by SMS message. You can confirm this for yourself by trying to respond to a particular message in a timeline of SMS messages in your phones SMS app. It's simply not possible.

If you do want to maintain multiple different conversations with a user between your application and their phone, then the best bet is to use different Twilio numbers to conduct different conversations. This is best explained in this article on [how to use a number pool to conduct multiple conversations](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134067-How-users-can-send-text-messages-to-each-other-over-Twilio) on the Twilio site

Comment: Thanks. This looks a bit like a limitation from Twilio side. Is there a plan for development towards something like this?

Comment: This is a limitation from SMS in general I'm afraid. The protocol itself doesn't have the concept of conversation, it's just a timeline of messages at best. Like I said, you can't respond directly to a specific message from within an SMS application, so there's no way your users would know how to do this either. A number pool, or a unique identifier in a message (which is a more awkward solution), is the only way to get around this.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this!